# UITableView change content if User is logged in

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm fairly new to IOS and I'm a bit confused about the way I can change my TableView's content depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

I have a MenuViewController which is a UIViewController with a tableView  and delegate/datasource protocols.

In MenuViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.credentialStore = [[CredentialStore alloc] init]; //ref to the object which defines my session
     [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:280.0f];
}
```

This is my getter for the cell's text

```
 - (NSArray *)menuItems {
     if (// Not logged in) {
         _menuItems = @[@"foo", @"bar", @"baz"];
         return _menuItems;
     } else {
        _menuItems = @[@"quux", @"other", @"other"];
        return _menuItems;
     }
 }

 - (NSArray *)menuItemsImages {
     if (// Not logged in) {
         _menuItemsImages = @[@"foo.png", @"bar.png", @"baz.png"];
         return _menuItemsImages; 
     } else {
         ....
         return _menuItemsImages;
     }
 }

 #pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return self.menuItems.count;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     }

     NSString *menuItem = self.menuItems[indexPath.row];

     cell.textLabel.text = menuItem;
     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.menuItemsImages[indexPath.row]];
     [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

     return cell;
  }
```

## pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     NSString *menuItem = self.menuItems[indexPath.row];


     if ([menuItem isEqualToString:@"foo"]) {
         self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fooNavigationVC"];
     } else if ([menuItem isEqualToString:@"bar"]) {
         self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"barNavigationController"];
     } else if ([menuItem isEqualToString:@"baz"]) {
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bazNavigationViewController"];
     }
    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
}
```

I'm a little confused because with that method the tableview sometimes does not update.

As far as I understand it right now I see two solutions:
 - Check is user is logged in ViewWillAppear and change the content
 - Set the Menu in ViewDidLoad and send a notification to the MenuViewController if user logs in, and [self.tableView reloadData];

It also have that checking which cell is pressed by comparing string is not very good.

If anyone could suggest some better ideas about how to change that menu's content depending on the user's logged ing or not would be great.
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I understand it right now I see two solutions: - Check is user is logged in ViewWillAppear and change the content - Set the Menu in ViewDidLoad and send a notification to the MenuViewController if user logs in, and [self.tableView reloadData];

Are you not doing any of this?  If you want the contents of a table view to change, you must call `reloadData` on that table view.  There's no other way that I know of to do it.  I don't know how you're handling the log in / log out logic, so I can't tell you what would be best here, but I'd guess a notification is probably a good starting place.

---

You are correct--comparing strings to determine which row was pressed and therefore which view to load is bad practice.

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is already sending an argument that tells us which cell was selected: the `indexPath`.

There are many problems with string comparison.  First of all, if you ever want to localize your app, the strings will be different depending on who is using the app because of all the different languages.  Second of all, string comparison is slow relative to just comparing a couple ints that make up an index path.  And third, sometimes you need to slightly change what the actual string is.  It could be something as simple as a typo.  The more places you have to type that string at, the more likely it is you make the typo, and the more time you have to spend double/triple checking every location to make sure every string is exactly the same--down to the capitalization.

Given that you appear to have just a single section but multiple rows, the simplest solution here would probably be a simple `enum`.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MenuIndexPath) {
    RowForFoo = 0,
    RowForBar = 1,
    RowForBaz = 2,
    RowForQuux = 0,
    RowForOther = 1,
    RowForAnother = 2
};
```

Now we'll use this enum both in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
switch(indexPath.row) {
    case RowForFoo:
        cell.textLabel.title = @"foo";
        break;
    // etc...
}
```

...

```
switch(indexPath.row) {
    case RowForFoo:
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard
            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fooNavigationVC"];
        break;
    // etc...
}
```

Now, if we need to change anything about how the cell at row "foo" looks, we only go to the the methods that adjust how cells look.  If we need to change anything about how the cell at row "foo" responds to being selected, we only go to that method.  And if we need to change the order in which row "foo" appears, we can go modify the `enum`.

If you're using multiple sections, just make an `enum` for the sections and an `enum` for the rows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't know about typedf enum and that looks great.

About which rows to display depending on the user's logged in or not, I was not clear enough.

I'm not sure if:
- the current state of the user (loggedin/loggedout) should be checked each time the menu appears (and would thus be in viewWillAppear right?). Which makes a lot of verifications.
- or if the menu cells are loaded in viewDidLoad, where the current state of user is checked once, and then the tableView is reloaded when a notification is received.

Comment: A table view's cells are loaded when its `reloadData` method is called.  A handful of `NSLog` statements can easily sort out whether this is called from `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, but just let the table view datasource methods check whether or not the user is logged in.  This will make the table data accurate every time its data is loaded.  Table data can be reloaded well after `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.